# how to type props for text area react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a react component that looks like this:

```
import { TextareaHTMLAttributes} from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const TextAreaElement = styled.textarea`
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: none;
  background: white;
`

const TextArea = (props: TextareaHTMLAttributes<any>) => {  <--- replace <any> here
  return <TextAreaElement {...props} />
}
```

I know I can do something like this, but would rather not have to add every prop manually:

```
const TextArea = ({placeholder} : {placeholder: string}) => {
  return <TextAreaElement placeholder={placeholder} />
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the props as regular HTML element

```
import React from "react";

const CustomTA = (props: React.HTMLProps<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
  return <textarea {...props} />;
};
```